# How to get a version of 3rd party Minecraft server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I would like to know which software (spigot etc.) is used by 3rd party Minecraft server and its version. Is there any way to do it?

I thought about rcon connection, but the server should support it.

Comment: It's not really clear what you are asking for. The spigot version? The 3rd party (who?) Minecraft Server version?

Comment: @TimmyJim, I have the IP of Minecraft server. I would like to know which minecraft server is there (incl. additional info - the server version, addons etc.).

Comment: @LA_ there is no real way to do what I believe you're asking, unless this information is made public. Is this a large server? Or a small one? If its a larger server maybe someone will know.

Answer (score 1):

If you are connected to the server, you might be able to find out more about it by looking at what commands are available.

On bukkit, spigot or similar servers (paper, etc.) you might be able to try the command `/version`, if it hasn't been restricted for whatever reason.